# Maps on the sphere.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, surfaces

This is a question from Barrett O'Neill's Elementary Differential Geometry.
Let $S^2$ be a sphere of radius $r$ centered at the origin. Following are three maps defined on $S^2$. The question is to describe the effect of these maps on the meridians and parallels of $S^2$. Let $p=(p_1,p_2,p_3)$ be a point on $S^2$.

1. $F(p)=-p$
2. $G(p_1,p_2,p_3)=(p_3,p_1,p_2)$
3. $H(p)=(\frac{p_1+p_2}{\sqrt 2},\frac{p_1-p_2}{\sqrt 2},-p_3)$

My thoughts : I am checking what these functions do to a single point of the sphere.  I suspect that all these are compositions of rotations and/or reflections. But I can't clearly state the axis of rotation or the plane of reflection. For example, the first one seems to be a reflection of a point across the xy plane and reflecting that point across xz plane. Though I'm not sure. I have absolutely no idea about the third one.

Any help is appreciated.Thanks for your time.

Comment: One way to look for axes of rotation and planes of reflection is to recognize that these are all linear maps, write down their extensions to $\mathbb{R}^3$, and analyze eigenspaces.

Comment: You're right on #1, although it's more simply reflection through the origin.  Think of #3 as a composition of two linear maps (one affecting the first two coordinates, one affecting only the third). For #2 it probably is easiest, as @Neal said, to write down the $3\times 3$ matrix and find an eigenvector for eigenvalue $1$. This will find the axis of rotation for you.

Comment: (1,1,1) is an eigenvector of eigenvalue 1, for the second function. What does this mean geometrically? Thanks for the useful comments.

Comment: I see. It is rotation by 2pi/3 radians and the axis of rotation is x=y=z. Thanks very much. I will work out the last one too.